# Concatenated text of JSON values with the same keys and save in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have this `JSON` from an API source:

```
"GREETINGS": [{
        "TYPE_OF_GREETING": "{EVENING}",
        "TEXT": "{G} {E} !!!!!"
    },
    {
        "TYPE_OF_GREETING": "{NIGHT}",
        "TEXT": "{G} {N} ... ."
    }
]
```

From some other API (SPARQL) I can generate this "vocabulary" object:

```
const vocabulary = {
    G: {
        en: "Good",
        de: "Guten",
        it: "Buona"
    },
    E: {
        en: "evening",
        de: "Abend",
        it: "serata"
    },
    N: {
        en: "night",
        de: "Nacht",
        it: "notte"
    }
};
```

Can you advice me the most efficient JavaScript code to get this result, please?

```
{
    eveningGreeting: {
        en: "Good evening !!!!!",
        de: "Guten Abend !!!!!",
        it: "Buona serata !!!!!"
    },
    nightGreeting: {
        en: "Good night ... .",
        de: "Guten Nacht ... .",
        it: "Buona notte ... ."
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Well there are already good codes below, but I just wanted to note, that the short-code for the german language is not "ge" but "de", so yeah, you might wanna fix it ;)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "MORNING -> {G} {M}" and "EVENING -> {G} {E}" in JSON?

Comment: DragonSkills99, AbsoluteBeginner -good catches, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function to convert the translations array to an object. I also keep a list of languages to replace the templated text with the translated text.

You can try like below.

```js
let GREETINGS =  [{
        "TYPE_OF_GREETING": "{MORNING}",
        "TEXT": "{G} {E} !!!!!"
    },
    {
        "TYPE_OF_GREETING": "{EVENING}",
        "TEXT": "{G} {N} ... ."
    }
]

const vocabulary = {
    G: {
        en: "Good",
        ge: "Guten",
        it: "Buona"
    },
    E: {
        en: "evening",
        ge: "Abend",
        it: "serata"
    },
    N: {
        en: "night",
        ge: "Nacht",
        it: "notte"
    }
};

const output = GREETINGS.reduce((prevValue, currValue) => {
    const name =
        currValue.TYPE_OF_GREETING.match(/[a-z,A-Z]/g)
            .join("")
            .toLowerCase() + "Greeting";

    const langs = ["en", "ge", "it"];
    prevValue[name] = langs.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        let formattedText = currValue.TEXT;
        Object.entries(vocabulary).forEach(([letter, mapping]) => {
            formattedText = formattedText.replace(`{${letter}}`, mapping[curr]);
        });
        prev[curr] = formattedText;
        return prev;
    }, {});

    return prevValue;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

NOTE: Use `map`, `reduce`, and `forEach` methods whenever possible.

Comment: @Kvetoslav, check this out !!

Comment: Great solution!!! Very clear. Marked as the accepted answer. Thank you very very much. Would you mind if I update my question as the usecase changed a l title bit?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on it.

The languages and vocabulary are auto-detected, you could add more without changing anything in the code.

```
// FIRST API CONSTANT
const greetings = {
    "GREETINGS": [{
        "TYPE_OF_GREETING": "{MORNING}",
        "TEXT": "{G} {E} !!!!!"
    },
    {
        "TYPE_OF_GREETING": "{EVENING}",
        "TEXT": "{G} {N} ... ."
    }
    ]
};

// SECOND API CONSTANT
const vocabulary = {
    G: {
        en: "Good",
        ge: "Guten",
        it: "Buona"
    },
    E: {
        en: "evening",
        ge: "Abend",
        it: "serata"
    },
    N: {
        en: "night",
        ge: "Nacht",
        it: "notte"
    }
};

// LIST ALL LANGUAGES
let languagesList = new Array();
for (let i in vocabulary.G) {
    languagesList.push(i);
}

// CREATE NEW OBJECT
let tNewObject = {};

for (let i in greetings['GREETINGS']) {
    // loops through greetings
    
    let type = greetings['GREETINGS'][i]["TYPE_OF_GREETING"].replace(/[{}]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    let textFormat = greetings['GREETINGS'][i]["TEXT"];
    
    let tProperty = type+'Greeting';
    tNewObject[tProperty] = {};
    
    for (let z=0;z<languagesList.length;z++) {
        // loops through languages
        
        let tValue = textFormat;
        let tLanguage = languagesList[z]
        
        for (let v in vocabulary) {
            // loops through vocabulary
            tValue = tValue.replace('{'+v+'}', vocabulary[v][tLanguage]);
        }
        
        tNewObject[tProperty][tLanguage] = tValue;
        
    }
    
}

console.log(tNewObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **object destructuring** yet?
I think it will can help you.